# NSLinguisticTagger giving different outputs on Mac vs iOS

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nlp

I am attempting to use NSLinguisticTagger to isolate the verbs in a sentence, but have run into an issue where the output is different depending on whether the code is run in an iOS vs. a MacOS program.

My code is the following:

```
NSString* text = @"The person is a 50 year old gentleman with a book who presents us with a conundrum.";
NSLinguisticTaggerOptions options = NSLinguisticTaggerOmitWhitespace | NSLinguisticTaggerOmitPunctuation | NSLinguisticTaggerJoinNames;
NSLinguisticTagger* tagger = [[NSLinguisticTagger alloc] initWithTagSchemes:@[NSLinguisticTagSchemeNameTypeOrLexicalClass]
                                                                    options:options];
tagger.string = text;
[tagger enumerateTagsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [tagger.string length])
                      scheme:NSLinguisticTagSchemeNameTypeOrLexicalClass
                     options:options
                  usingBlock:^(NSString *tag, NSRange tokenRange, NSRange sentenceRange, BOOL *stop) {
                      NSString *token = [text substringWithRange:tokenRange];
                      NSLog(@"%@: %@", token, tag);
                  }];
```

Running this code snippet in an **OSX** program, I correctly get the following output (**"presents"** is CORRECTLY identified as a verb):

```
[                    AppDelegate (0x101b0bcb0)]: The: Determiner
[                    AppDelegate (0x101b0bcb0)]: person: Noun
[                    AppDelegate (0x101b0bcb0)]: is: Verb
[                    AppDelegate (0x101b0bcb0)]: a: Determiner
[                    AppDelegate (0x101b0bcb0)]: 50: Number
[                    AppDelegate (0x101b0bcb0)]: year: Noun
[                    AppDelegate (0x101b0bcb0)]: old: Adjective
[                    AppDelegate (0x101b0bcb0)]: gentleman: Noun
[                    AppDelegate (0x101b0bcb0)]: with: Preposition
[                    AppDelegate (0x101b0bcb0)]: a: Determiner
[                    AppDelegate (0x101b0bcb0)]: book: Noun
[                    AppDelegate (0x101b0bcb0)]: who: Pronoun
[                    AppDelegate (0x101b0bcb0)]: presents: Verb
[                    AppDelegate (0x101b0bcb0)]: us: Pronoun
[                    AppDelegate (0x101b0bcb0)]: with: Preposition
[                    AppDelegate (0x101b0bcb0)]: a: Determiner
[                    AppDelegate (0x101b0bcb0)]: conundrum: Noun
```

However, the same exact code block in an **iOS** program results in the following output (**"presents"** is INCORRECTLY identified as a noun):

```
[                      AppDelegate (0x8d2f000)]: The: Determiner
[                      AppDelegate (0x8d2f000)]: person: Noun
[                      AppDelegate (0x8d2f000)]: is: Verb
[                      AppDelegate (0x8d2f000)]: a: Determiner
[                      AppDelegate (0x8d2f000)]: 50: Number
[                      AppDelegate (0x8d2f000)]: year: Noun
[                      AppDelegate (0x8d2f000)]: old: Adjective
[                      AppDelegate (0x8d2f000)]: gentleman: Noun
[                      AppDelegate (0x8d2f000)]: with: Preposition
[                      AppDelegate (0x8d2f000)]: a: Determiner
[                      AppDelegate (0x8d2f000)]: book: Noun
[                      AppDelegate (0x8d2f000)]: who: Pronoun
[                      AppDelegate (0x8d2f000)]: presents: Noun
[                      AppDelegate (0x8d2f000)]: us: Pronoun
[                      AppDelegate (0x8d2f000)]: with: Preposition
[                      AppDelegate (0x8d2f000)]: a: Determiner
[                      AppDelegate (0x8d2f000)]: conundrum: Noun
```

Does anyone know why I am getting the different outputs, and how I can correctly get the iOS program to identify **presents** as a verb?

Answer (score 2):

The tagger is stochastic, i.e., it always makes errors. Due to limited resources of iOS devices, the underlying language model is less precise than that in the OS X version. If you want higher accuracy, use a rule-based parser. You'd have to deal with ambiguity though.